# Build multiplication table in matlab

Tags: matlab

for school exercise i need to build an multiplication table 10x10 using element-by-element function, and make it as short as possible.
this is the code i wrote (working but too long), please suggest some twicks to this code.
thanks in advance (:

```
base=zeros(10);
oneten=[1:1:10];
base(1,:)=1.*oneten;
base(2,:)=2.*oneten;
base(3,:)=3.*oneten;
base(4,:)=4.*oneten;
base(5,:)=5.*oneten;
base(6,:)=6.*oneten;
base(7,:)=7.*oneten;
base(8,:)=8.*oneten;
base(9,:)=9.*oneten;
base(10,:)=10.*oneten
```

Comment: In your example, you do not need to use element-by-element multiplication as your are multiplying scalars by vectors. `1*oneten` will give the same output as `1.*oneten`.

Comment: 'Using element by element function' is not very clear. If your answer needs contain an elementwise operation, you can simply end your solution by multiplying `.*1`. If you are only allowed to use elementwise operations, I the second solution by daniel is probably best.

Comment: I would answer like francesco because the vector outer product is arguably the  most natural way to address the task, but it seems clear that Daniel's solution is a bit faster: `bsxfun(@times, one_to_n, one_to_n')`. Kudos also to Daniel.

Answer (score 4):

Do something like this:

```
(1:10)' * (1:10)
```

**EDIT --->**

I have tested the speed of the solutions suggested by Daniel, me, Luis Mendo and David, when N is large:

```
N = 100;    % number of iterations
runtime_a = zeros(N, 1);    % runtime of Daniel's solution
runtime_b = zeros(N, 1);    % runtime of the obvious solution
runtime_c = zeros(N, 1);    % runtime of Luis Mendo's solution
runtime_d = zeros(N, 1);    % runtime of Luis Mendo's solution
runtime_e = zeros(N, 1);    % runtime of David's solution
n = 5000;    % number of elements
one_to_n = 1:n;
for hh = 1:N
  % Solution by Daniel R.
  tic, a = bsxfun(@times, one_to_n, one_to_n'); runtime_a(hh) = toc;
  clear a
  tic, b = one_to_n' * one_to_n; runtime_b(hh) = toc;
  clear b
  % Solution by Luis Mendo
  tic, c = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) (x:x:n*x).', one_to_n, 'uni', false)); runtime_c(hh) = toc;
  clear c
  % Solution by Luis Mendo.
  tic, d = cumsum(repmat(one_to_n, [n 1])); runtime_d(hh) = toc;
  clear d
  % Solution by David
  tic, [A, B] = meshgrid(one_to_n); e = A.*B; runtime_e(hh) = toc;
  clear e
end

% Check mean and standard deviation:
mean([runtime_a, runtime_b, runtime_c, runtime_d, runtime_e])
std([runtime_a, runtime_b, runtime_c, runtime_d, runtime_e])
```

Results are:

```
% mean:
0.105048900691251   0.188570704057917   0.491929288458701   0.787045026437718   0.979624197407329
% standard deviation:
0.034274873626281   0.077388368324427   0.163983982925543   0.285395301735065   0.372693172505310
```

So, apparently, when N is large, Daniel's solution is the fastest.

Comment: This is the shortest method as long as element-by-element multiplication is not a requirement.

Comment: It is completely bizarre that `one_to_n' * one_to_n` is slower than `bsxfun(@times, one_to_n, one_to_n')`.  I mean, I love `bsxfun`, but this just seems tragic.

Comment: (Actually I was quite shocked too!)

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of it: other possibilities are

- ```
  cumsum(repmat(1:10,[10 1]))
  ```
- ```
  cell2mat(arrayfun(@(n) (n:n:10*n).',1:10,'uni',false))
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
oneten=[(1:10)]
base = bsxfun(@times,oneten,oneten')
```

preallocation (`base=zeros(10);`)is unnessecary in this case.

And another solution which is easier to understand:

```
base=zeros(10);
oneten=[(1:10)];
for k=oneten
    base(k,:)=k.*oneten;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[A,B]=meshgrid(1:10);
A.*B
```

Uses element-by-element multiplication

Answer (score 0):

My answer is using nested for loops:

```
for i = (1:10)
    for j = (1:10) 
        fprintf('%d\t',i*j); 
    end 
    fprintf('\n'); 
end
```