# initialize 2-D array with values based on index oneliner

Tags: matlab, list-comprehension

In python its possible to do a list comprehension like `[a+b for a in range(n) for b in range(n)]`. Is there a way to do this in MATLAB? if it were a 1D array I could say `arrayfun(@(a)a,1:n)`, but I can't find a concise adaptable way.

Possible not as concise way:

```
for ii=1:n
    a(ii,:) = ii:n+ii-1;
end
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`bsxfun`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).

Comment: so you want [a(1,:) + b(1,:); a(2,:)+b(2,:), ...,] that's it?

Comment: All but the top voted answer can be used for addition as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757757/build-multiplication-table-in-matlab

Comment: And you could use the built-in [hankel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html) function: `hankel(1:n,n:2*n-1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`bsxfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) can do the job indeed:

```
n = 5 ;
a = bsxfun( @(x,y) x+y-1 , (1:n), (1:n).')

a =
     1     2     3     4     5
     2     3     4     5     6
     3     4     5     6     7
     4     5     6     7     8
     5     6     7     8     9
```

---

As Luis Mendo rightly reminded us, `bsxfun` will be even faster with the built-in functions (the list is in the documentation), so if you can get away with using a simple built-in function you should do it:

```
a = bsxfun( @plus , (1:n), (0:n-1).')
```

If your function is too complex, then just define it explicitly as in the top example.

Comment: `bsxfun` is faster with its builtin functions: `a = bsxfun(@plus, (1:n), (0:n-1).')`

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to use [`hankel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html):

```
>> n = 5;
>> hankel(1:n, n:2*n-1)

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5
     2     3     4     5     6
     3     4     5     6     7
     4     5     6     7     8
     5     6     7     8     9
```

Comment: Nice. Sometimes I wonder how can one remember all the exotic functions Matlab has.

Comment: @Hoki This matrix is a special case of a [*Hankel matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix); you only have to know what such matrices are called and that MATLAB provides a function for generating them.